# Struggling to copy files together, issue downloading voxceleb on windows

Tags: command-line, file-transfer, compression, zip, copy

```
copy /b vox1_dev_wav_partaa+vox1_dev_wav_partab+vox1_dev_wav_partac+vox1_dev_wav_partad vox1_dev_wav.zip
```

Trying to use this to merge 4 files into a compressed file, but it keeps saying that 'The system cannot find the file specified'

[https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/voxceleb/vox1.html](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/voxceleb/vox1.html) (trying to download vox 1 from this website, but the command is written for linux)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does `dir` show the files? Have you `cd`'d into the correct directory? Are you doing this in PowerShell or in the traditional Cmd (Command Prompt)?

Comment: `copy` does not download

Comment: @Yorik - though that is, of course, obvious, it hadn't occurred to me that the OP hadn't even downloaded the files yet ;)) Well spotted.